# firefox addon-sdk unit-tests

Tags: unit-testing, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Did anybody used the unit-tests from the addon-sdk(cfx test)?

I made a test that looks like this:

```
exports.test_open_tab = function(test) {
   const tabs = require("tabs");
   tabs.open({
       url: "http://valid url with lots of params",
       onReady: function(tab) {
           test.done();
       }
   });

   test.waitUntilDone(600*1000);
};
```

basically this **should** open a tab, wait 600seconds, and them mark it as passed.

It **actually** displays a lot of errors and warning in the console from the loaded page(jquery and google analytics stuff, used by the loaded page) and then it marks the test as failed.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious issue is that you don't actually have any test results. If the fact that `onReady()` is called is a positive result you should write:

```
 onReady: function(tab) {
     test.pass("onReady called");
     test.done();
 }
```

Btw, the only case where it would wait 600 seconds is if `onReady` isn't called for some reason. Otherwise your `test.done()` call will complete the test execution.

You can somewhat reduce the number of warnings logged by disabling [`javascript.options.strict` preference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/javascript.options.strict). However, these warnings might indicate real issues and in current Firefox versions it probably makes more sense to switch off display of JavaScript and CSS warnings in the console.

Comment: according to https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/api-utils/docs/unit-test.html, it just waits for `test.done()` to be called. I'll try calling `.pass()` when i get the chance(i dont have access to the dev computer atm)

Comment: do you know of any way to ignore warnings and errors generated by the webpage, but display addon errors? My addon has to load some texts from webpages, and so i need to be able to open pages and then call some addon function in order to actually test it.

Comment: yes, test.pass did the trick. still didn;t get rid of the webpage errors though

Comment: @Quamis did you ever figure out how to ignore warnings and errors generated by the webpage?

Comment: @willlma no, i finished the project i was working on back then and didn't look back. In the meantime the SDK evolved a lot, i'd expect most of the problems i encoutered are now fixed

Comment: @Quamis Yeah, they're doing a fantastic job, but my tests are flooded with with pages' logs.